# Possible non-determinism in transcan from rms package

Tags: r, logistic

I ran into the following problem while using `transcan()` function from the [rms](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html) package. For a fixed dataset, I ran `transcan()` to transform a set of 15 variables on 2 separate Linux machines - the final transformations were exactly inverses of each other, i.e. T1 = C-T2, where C is a constant. I am sending you plots showing the 2 transformations for one of these variables.

Would you have an idea about why transforms are differerent? Is there some non-determinism within `transcan()`? Are there any parameter settings that would allow `transcan()` to produce the exact same transformations?

My `transcan()` invocation is as follows:

```
transcan(formula_transform, data=w, transformed=T, imputed=F, pl=F)
```

Btw, the `transcan()` convergence criteria is identical on both machines.

Images of the transforms:

https://picasaweb.google.com/102296104801173987070/Stats?authuser=0&feat=directlink

Comment: The Picasa link seems to be broken; can you fix it please?

Comment: You sent me an e-mail about this 2-3 weeks ago which I'm sorry I haven't had time to deal with.  I will do so soon.  Note that `transcan` is in the R `Hmisc` package.  Be sure to include self-contained code that causes the problem, in any posting, and to define versions of R and packages used.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the broken link. here's the correct one: https://picasaweb.google.com/102296104801173987070/Stats?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCPL50omx-4bH1QE&feat=directlink

Comment: Dr. Harrell, I will post more details with self-contained code soon. thanks!